How to interpret ordinal data in logistic regression, both negative coefficients
I have a logistic regression model that has a bunch of variables in it, including a variable of rurality that has three levels (urban, rural 1, and rural 2). That is an ordinal variable.
My model has the .L and .Q versions of the relationship, which I know to be their linear and quadratic relationship. However, I'm unsure of how to interpret them, especially the quadratic one.
Here is a screenshot:

I believe the linear version means that as rurality increases, the odds of the outcome increases. However, for the quadratic version, does that refer to the effect's severity or the actual relationship? By that, does the inverse relationship increase or decrease in severity from the second to the third level compared to the first and second levels?

Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot.
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If
it helps, we have some
resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated.
